# Replace OFFSET with INDEX (EXCEL)

Tags: excel

I'm using a formula with OFFSET, I would like to replace OFFSET by INDEX, so I can get the data in another file. can anybody help me?

```
=OFFSET(DATA!$C$1,MATCH(C2,DATA!$C$2:$C$3500,0),8,COUNTIF(DATA!$C$2:$C$3500,C2))
```

This formula I use as a list, within the data validation.

Tks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(DATA!$K$2:$K$3500,MATCH(C2,DATA!$C$2:$C$3500,0)):INDEX(DATA!$K$2:$K$3500,MATCH(C2,DATA!$C$2:$C$3500,0)+COUNTIF(DATA!$C$2:$C$3500,C2))
```

Or with FILTER():

```
=FiLTER(DATA!$K$2:$K$3500,DATA!$C$2:$C$3500=C2)
```

Comment: tks!!!
I verified that it correctly fetched the data within the table, but when I insert it into the data validation it does not accept it. Msg: "you cannot use reference operators (like unions...)... for data validation criteria."

Comment: That condition was not part of the question.  You will need to stick with offset.  There is no way to do what you want using index with data validation.

Comment: That being said, if you have Office 365 Excel you can create a dynamic formula in a hidden sheet and then refer to that dynamic array.

Comment: Ohh Tks. I'll try

Comment: Mayukh Bhattacharya, I've done tks

Comment: I wanted to edit and not delete. I spelled it wrong, I apologize for my English. 
Mayukh Bhattacharya

Comment: Only formula filter?

Comment: @dcantere it will not work directly in Data Validation either.  You would put that in a cell and it will spill the results if you have Office 365.